# Rails View Save Button Disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, prawn

I'm running a controller action "save" by pressing the view's save button.  The "post" action redirects to a "print_pdf" action which then renders a pdf via prawn. The trouble is the save button remains disabled. You cannot press the button but the other controls in the view work. The only way to bring the save button back to an enabled state is by clicking on browser "refresh".  I have tried redirect_to :back and all kinds of other hacks but end up an error.  You cannot perform more than one redirect per controller action.  Any ideas how to enable the save button or why it remains/causes disabled?  Please.

```
#view
<%= form_for(@pdf_report_run) do |f| %>
  <div> class="some_class">
    <%= f.submit("Save", class: 'btn btn-primary') %>

#controller
def create
  format.html { redirect_to print_pdf(format: 'pdf') }
end

def print_pdf
  @self = self
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf {render layout: false}
  end
end

# file print_pdf.pdf
# this contains the view the controller will render
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
   ...
end
# the line below is the last line that gets ran (last line of the controller's view)
@self.send_data pdf, filename: 'file_name.pdf', type: 'application/pdf'
# i've tried redirect_to and render here but won't allow another
```

Comment: How about adding the code from your view and controller, or are you expecting us to hack into your local machine and look at your code that way?

Comment: Please also paste the view code where the "Save" button resides.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Rails 5 feature, to resolve this here's a quick hack

Instead of using `<%= f.submit("Save", class: 'btn btn-primary') %>`, use this

```
<%= button_tag 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Hope that helps!